# Count the number of labels in ClearCase

Tags: clearcase

In my VOB there are a lot of labels (the type, not labels applied to a file).  I want to find out how many there are but it is too many to count by hand.  How can I get a count of how many label types I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
cleartool find /vobs/vobsname -kind lbtype -print | wc -l
```

It came up with the answer 12291 on one of the VOBs I work with (one that is over 15 years old).

Note that I've added `-s` to the `lstype` command - I got a misleading line count first time because of that.  Here are some timing tests (`ct` is effectively an alias for `cleartool` that takes less typing - and causes occasional confusion with the 'call terminal' program on Unixes with archaic communications software still installed):

```
$ time ct find . -kind lbtype -print | wc -l
12291
   27.08s real     1.77s user     1.30s system
$ time ct lstype -kind lbtype -s -unsorted | sort | uniq -c |
>     tee /tmp/x1 | wc -l
12292
   58.10s real     4.96s user     4.66s system
$ time ct lstype -kind lbtype -s -unsorted | wc -l                      
12292
   94.97s real     4.48s user     4.52s system
$ time ct lstype -kind lbtype -s -unsorted | wc -l
12292
   73.66s real     4.69s user     4.91s system
$ time ct find . -kind lbtype -print | wc -l                            
12291
   25.39s real     2.19s user     1.53s system
$
```

Hmmm...very variable performance on the `lstype`; the performance of `find` is more consistent and quicker.  YMMV!

I expect that someone added a label between runs.

I'm not sure how to assess the performance differences; the results seem to be the same.

---

Further timings on my machine (Linux x86/64):

```
$ time ct lstype -local -s -kind lbtype -invob /vobs/vobname -unsorted | wc -l
12292
   79.49s real     1.27s user     1.87s system
$ time ct lstype -local -s -kind lbtype -invob /vobs/vobname -unsorted | wc -l
12292
   36.87s real     1.39s user     1.79s system
$ time ct lstype -local -s -kind lbtype -invob /vobs/vobname -unsorted | wc -l
12292
   32.30s real     1.33s user     1.92s system
$ time ct find /vobs/vobname -kind lbtype -print | wc -l
12291
   21.68s real     0.81s user     0.67s system
$ time ct find /vobs/vobname -kind lbtype -print | wc -l
12291
   21.87s real     0.76s user     0.68s system
$ time ct lstype -local -s -kind lbtype -invob /vobs/vobname -unsorted | wc -l
12292
   32.94s real     1.26s user     1.78s system
$
```

All operations in the same view, with typing time only for the gap between 'ct lstype' and 'ct find' (otherwise, using history to re-execute).  I'm not sure why there's the 12291 vs 12292 discrepancy.

```
$ ct -version
ClearCase version 7.0.1 (Wed May 30 17:04:58 EDT 2007)
7.0.1.0-RATL-RCC-IFIX01 (Wed Sep 19 16:08:10 EDT 2007)
7.0.1.1-RATL-RCC-RWP (Wed Dec 05 15:35:18 EST 2007)
7.0.1.1-RATL-RCC (Wed Dec 05 16:29:24 EST 2007)
7.0.1.1-RATL-RCC-IFIX02 (Tue May 13 14:43:13 EDT 2008)
7.0.1.2-RATL-RCC (Tue Jul 29 14:40:53 EDT 2008)
7.0.1.2-RATL-RCC-RWP (Tue Jul 29 17:31:59 EDT 2008)
7.0.1.3-RATL-RCC (Wed Nov 12 13:22:16 EST 2008)
7.0.1.4-RATL-RCC (Wed Feb 18 13:00:21 EST 2009)
@(#) MVFS version 7.0.1.4 (Tue Dec  9 00:34:57 2008) built at $Date: 2010-06-11.13:25:31 (UTC) $
cleartool                         7.0.1.4 (Wed Dec 10 00:55:12 EST 2008)
db_server                         7.0.1.4 (Tue Dec  9 01:09:22 EST 2008)
VOB database schema version: 54
$
```

Comment: Err... much slower than a `lstype -unsorted` in my opinion.

Comment: ... Or not ;) +1 for the comparison. I will test that tomorrow.

Comment: @VonC: you can count me surprised (too). 12K labels over 16 years is 750 labels per year, or 2 per day.  That's in the right ballpark.  I'll experiment some when I get time...

Comment: Can you test with `ct lstype -local -s -kind lbtype -invob /vobs/avob -unsorted`? Do you see an amelioration when adding the `-local` option to the `lstype` command?

Comment: @VonC: see new information - I've no idea what weirdness in my setup leaves `ct find` running faster than `ct lstype`.

Comment: @Jonathan: I confirm that ct find is faster (using a view might help). The discrepancy is explained by the extra line produced by the `ct lstype`: "`Local Types:`"

Comment: @VonC: Thanks.  That's all very interesting.  Object DBMS are funny things :D

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`lstype`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lstype.htm)**:

```
ct lstype -local -s -kind lbtype -invob \avob -unsorted
```

Then you can pipe the result to a wc to count the label types.

Don't forget the '`unsorted`' parameter: the result will be quicker to be computed.

[Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608582/count-the-number-of-labels-in-clearcase/4608802#4608802) might be faster (not sure, wothout the `-local` for the `lstype`), but can't get *all* the labels (not the global ones, i.e. the ones from the hierarchy of adminvob).

The `ct lstype` above:

- list only the local label types (remove the `-local` to list all label types)
- don't necessitate a view with mounted vobs to operate

Comment: Tested: lstype is longer (x1.5). At least you don't have to start/create a view and mount vobs to make it work.